# How can I know if an ARM library is using hardfp?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm

I don't have access to the build command, I just have the library in my system.

I guess I could build an hardfp executable that links against it and test, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: I would try to disassemble the library and look for the corresponding hardfp instructions. The presence or absence of those instructions is a good indicator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Execute `readelf -A library.so`: if the list of printed tags contains `Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers`, then it is a `hardfp` binary, otherwise assume `softfp`.

E.g. `readelf -A /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6` will produce

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

On the other side, `readelf -A /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libm.so.6` produces

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

Comment: Could you tell me why that command doesn't produce any output on my AMD64 Linux box?

Comment: The library is not for ARM or the library is for old ARM ABI (OABI) or your `readelf` does not support parsing ARM EABI attributes

Comment: My lib is AMD64, but `man (1) readelf` says `       -A
       --arch-specific
    Displays architecture-specific information in the file, if there is
    any.` Why does it work with ARM only?

Comment: AMD64 ELF does not define arch-specific attributes section

Comment: Does this solution work with static libraries? Does object code compiled into the library's archive also count as ELF files and have these attributes?

Comment: @Spidey I think you'd need to extract an archive member (object file) to use this method

Comment: @MaratDukhan Can we use -mfloat-abi=softfp with a hard float binary?

Comment: @MaratDukhan In my experience, `readelf -A <archive>` will give you the attributes for each contained object file, so you shouldn't need to extract the archive.

Answer (score 8):

Use `readelf`.

Here's some example output from one an ARM build of Poco:

```
$ readelf libPocoFoundation.so -h
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x61e50
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1078048 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000402, has entry point, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
```

In the flags section, it will list data about the elf file. These are defined in the [ARM ELF Specification](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf), check table 4-2. In my case, this was built with a hard float compiler, so hard-float is listed as a flag.

On a soft float library, the flags line looks like this:

```
Flags: 0x5000202, has entry point, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
```

Comment: The `hardfp`/`softfp` flags were added only recently, and only the newest toolchains support them. Older toolchains indicate floating-point ABI only in EABI attributes section.

Comment: Quoting from the referenced document: `EF_ARM_ABI_FLOAT_HARD
(0x00000400)
(ABI version 5 and later)`: _Set in executable file headers (e_type = ET_EXEC or ET_DYN) to note that
the executable file was built to conform to the hardware floating-point
procedure-call standard.
Compatible with legacy (pre version 5) gcc use as EF_ARM_VFP_FLOAT._

Answer (score -2):

Use `objdump -d` to disassemble, then grep for some floating point commands. I'm not sure whether objdump will produce UAL-compliant assembly, so try old syntax too. It might be even easier to watch for register names rather than command mnemonics, but there could be false positives.