# Oracle JDK1.8 hard float not working

Tags: java, embedded

We are trying to install JVM on our 32 bit ARM V7 running on linux OS . I downloaded  jdk-8u101-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html , extracted and copied the jre folder into our rootfs and booted the system.I navigated to the folder where it is present and was trying to verify whether is was installed properly. But i observed the following error.

```
$ java -version
  -sh: java: not found
```

though it is present in the pat.

1) I verified and confirmed the JRE binary is actually built for 32 bit ARM and all the dependent libraries are present. I have VFP enabled in my kernel and compiled it with *mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp* option.But this doesn't occur on repeating the same process with https://community.oracle.com/ ejdk-8u101-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz .It works fine and i am able to execute simple hello world with soft float JRE unlike hard float JRE. Has anyone faced this issue. If so, what is the solution ?

2) An other question is,  do we have jdk1.8 with soft float abi ? What  i see is it only hard float.

It would be great if  any one can throw pointers on these.

Comment: Try `./java` instead.

Comment: *What* is present in the PATH? Are you sure you have the full path to the `bin` directory in the PATH? Can you show it? Have you checked that it is executable? Have you checked that the command `java` is not aliased or defined as a function?

Comment: Most of the time, the trivial things bite where it hurts the most... I'm sure this has nothing to do with FP, but a PATH issue. Or a file that has not been downloaded properly. Or disk got full during extraction. Or a permission issue...

Comment: @all : I already have tried ./java and it gives the same result. I have it verified to be an executable. I am pretty much sure that the extraction has been done properly with enough disk space.

Comment: try `sudo find / -executable -iname "java"` and please post the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think your LinxuOS library is for softfp only.  Refer to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555594/how-can-i-know-if-an-arm-library-is-using-hardfp) to use `readelf` to check your system has hardfp or not. I saw the same message on my target board which is softfp.